# Oracle Apex How to write Server side PL/SQL expression code

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an Apex page IG with a separate Continue button.

When the button is pressed, it asks for confirmation and submits the page.
The button is defined by dynamic action.
If true, JS code is used to display the confirmation message.

Now i need to add conditon on that button, which only when satisfied should it proceed.

So Button: Continue
Dynamic Action: Submit
Server Side condition for this needs to be soemthing like this:

```
Declare
empcode NUMBER(20);
prom_emp_code NUMBER(20);
Begin
Select emp_code into empcode from employees where emp_id = :P1_EMPID;
Select p_emp_code into prom_emp_code from promoted_employees where emp_id = :P1_EMPID;
IF empcode !=p_emp_code
THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT_PUT_LINE('The employee code needs to be validated before proceeding');
END IF;
END;
```

I tried fitting this in Server side condition -> Expression-> PL/SQL but it threw error which was obvious.

How can i add this as PL/SQL expression, so that if empcode is not equal to p_emp_code the execution should stop and give the message in dbms output.
Else it'd proceed and show the JS code as supposed to by the submit DA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view, for confirmation use built-in Apex capabilities (i.e. skip JavaScript of your own):

[image]

As of **validation** message: do exactly that - a validation. Set it to a function that returns error text and slightly modify code you posted:

[image]

```
declare
  empcode number;
  prom_emp_code number;
 begin
   select emp_code into empcode from employees 
   where emp_id = :P1_EMPID;

   select p_emp_code into prom_emp_code 
   from promoted_employees
   where emp_id = :P1_EMPID;

   if empcode <> p_emp_code then
      return 'The employee code needs to be validated';
   end if;
 end;
```

---

So:

- when you click the button, Apex will want you to confirm the action
- validation will *fire*, check whether values match and - if not - raise an error with a message (otherwise, it'll skip it and submit the page)

Comment: Thank you. When i try to validated it says PL/SQL exxpression is of the wrong type and points to the return statement. Does the return type also need to be declared here?

Comment: Did you set validation **type** to function body that returns **error text**? Because, there's also a function body that returns a **Boolean** (which is quite a different thing).

Comment: Yes sorry. i had set the other one. This worked. thank you so much!!

Comment: I just had one query if you could answer since i am new to apex DA's. Can this function body returning error text not be used in server side condition in other scenarios? how can this be used ?

Comment: Sure, you can use such a code in server-side condition as well. Choose the "function body" as its type; it is then really supposed to return a Boolean, so you'd just `return empcode = p_emp_code;` which means that - if they are equal, function will return TRUE and nothing will happen. Otherwise, it'll return FALSE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253554/discussion-between-velocity-and-littlefoot).

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple actions in a dynamic action that have dependencies (like action 2 depends on the outcome of action 1) then you need to work with page items.

- Set a page item to a value in action 1
- create a *client side condition* that depends on that page item in action 2.

Server side conditions are evaluated at page render time - they cannot be used in your use case.

Note: `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` has not meaning in an apex context. It can be used in clients like sqlcl, slqdeveloper, sqlplus but not in Oracle APEX. There is no console in what behaviour are you expecting ?